# Reading numpy arrays written in a text file using str() method

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a file in which I have written a couple of numpy arrays using

```
file.write('array1 = ' + str(array1) + '\n')
file.write('array2 = ' + str(array2) + '\n')
....
```

Therefore, the file looks like

```
array1 = [1.000 2.000]
array2 = [1.000 2.000 
   3.000 4.000]
```

(In the example, I've split the line corresponding to `array2` after the second element; in reality, it is split after the fourth element or so.)

I now would like to read the file into another Python script so as to have `array1` and `array2` initialized with the values saved into the file.

Obviously one could think of some solution using (rather complicated) regular expressions, etc.  But I was wondering if there is a built-in routine for this purpose?

Comment: Why would you not save it as a pickle or a json instead?

Comment: It's good to use Serialization and Deserialization of Python Objects

Comment: Why do you think simply dumping the string representation of your arrays would be a reasonable way to store the data? Numpy arrays come with a built-in, efficient, and portable serializaiton format, using the function `np.save`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!  I DON'T think dumping the string representation is a reasonable way of storing data.  It just happened that I have stored the data in that 'unreasonable' way, and need a quick way to load them.

Comment: Well, if you can't go back and use `np.save` and `np.load`, or even `pickle`, then I'm afraid you'll be stuck parsing that output...

Comment: If you can manage to extract the r.h.s.s and are ok with everything turned into row vectors you can use the `matrix` constructor and then convert to array.